# build source in atom editor

Tags: sublimetext, atom-editor

I have been using Sublime Text for last few years and have been building my source code by creating my own custom build file. I am planning to give atom editor a spin but I can't find any provision for building my source file. Is there any way to create a build system inside atom editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [the build package](https://atom.io/packages/build). It lets you use [different plugins](https://github.com/noseglid/atom-build/blob/master/build-tools.md) to interact with different build toolchains, or [specify a custom one](https://atom.io/packages/build#specifying-a-custom-build-command).